# H2o with predict_json: "Error: Could not find or load main class water.util.H2OPredictor"?

Tags: r, h2o

I tried to use the H2o predict_json in R,

```
h2o.predict_json(modelpath, jsondata)
```

and got the error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class water.util.H2OPredictor
```

I am using h2o_3.20.0.8.

I searched the documentation from H2o but didn't help.

```
> h2o.predict_json(modelpath, jsondata)
$error
[1] "Error: Could not find or load main class water.util.H2OPredictor"

Warning message:
In system2(java, args, stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE) :
  running command ''java'  -Xmx4g -cp .:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/mylib/Models/h2o-genmodel.jar:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/mylib/Models:genmodel.jar:/ water.util.H2OPredictor  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/mylib/Models/mymodel.zip '[{"da1":252,"da2":22,"da3":62,"da4":63,"da5":84.83}]' 2>&1' had status 1
```

Comment: Is the model you are trying to load also from h2o version 3.20.0.8 or from a later version of h2o, if so please post what version you were trying to upload from. For examples on how to use this function please the docs: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.predict_json.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing your `h2o-genmodel.jar` file - this is what the error message `Could not find or load main class water.util.H2OPredictor` indicates. You may want to provide all the arguments to checkoff that you have everything:

`h2o.predict_json(model, json, genmodelpath, labels, classpath, javaoptions)`

documentation [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.predict_json.html)

Comment: thanks Lauren! Just followed the link and the problem is solved.